# Excel conditional formatting after data refresh

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to apply conditional formatting to a cell in Excel 2016, to indicate if the value has increased or decreased after a data refresh. 
I know how to do this using Icon sets etc. if I am comparing a cell value with another cell value, but what if you have no other cell to compare it to?

So lets say I have a value in A1. This value gets updated after refresh. I want to show that the value in A1 has increased or decreased for that one cell.

I hope I am making sense.

Comment: you will only be able to use one value per cell in a cond format

Comment: Interesting question. I understand exactly what you're asking, but unfortunately I don't know of any way to accomplish this. It _might_ be possible to do with VBA (which isn't my area of expertise), but even that is doubtful.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to have another cell to relate it to, say B1 containing:

```
=A1-B1
```

Then clear any existing CF from A1, select it and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=B1<0
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select formatting of choice (I suggest red fill)  <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Then add another rule:

```
=B1>0
```

(I suggest green fill).

Above requires iterative calculation to be turned on (in Options) with Maxium Iterations set to `1`.